# Managing svn repository - automatic merging or patching?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn

I've got problem with manage svn repository in our company.
We cooperate with outsourcing programmers - they develop software and send it every week to us. 
But now there are some programmers in our company - and they write some new functions for this software. This outsourcing company haven't got access to our changes.

I have problem with merging these versions.

Should I create patches with our changes, or... what approach should I have?
What if there will be conflicts? (I'm sure, there will be some conflicts)

I would automate this...

Comment: What about using a distributed version control system (git, mercurial...) ?

Comment: You can't automate this. You chose a model where developers (outsourced) modify code without even having access to the actual, last version of the code (the one modified by your own devs). That can't work well. Why don't all the developers share the same code repository?

Comment: It is not my decision, unfortunately... No git, no mercurial, only svn, no access to code for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably have either team work out of their own branch and regularly (probably weekly, since the outsourced team submits their code each week) merge the two branches into trunk. You're right, you probably will hit conflicts but in your case, that can't be avoided. At least if its taken care of regularly it should be manageable.